# How do I solve the "Machine could not configure the network interface" while using the Bitnami ERPNext virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, bitnami, erpnext

I imported the image as directed on the Bitnami website however when I started it up it shows the error below.
[Error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cekzI.png)

I've tried to run

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/configure_app_domain --domain IP-ADDRESS
```

With IP-ADDRESS as 127.0.0.1 but it still won't connect on the host machine.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, is this the first time you are deploying the Bitnami ERPNext solution in your computer? Please note that it requires 2GB of RAM to work properly, do the VM and the host machine have enough resources to run the app?

Comment: Yes this is the first time I am deploying the Bitnami ERPNext solution, I have 8GB of Ram so that should not be an issue on the memory side. I imported the VM multiple times without anything running but I don't know why it shows the network error. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Did you try other methods to configure the network interface in the VM? (Bridge, NAT, ...)